# Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

Tags: r, prediction, r-formula

I'm tring to use neuralnet for prediction.

Create some X:

```
x <- cbind(seq(1, 50, 1), seq(51, 100, 1))
```

Create Y:

```
y <- x[,1]*x[,2]
```

Give them a names

```
colnames(x) <- c('x1', 'x2')
names(y) <- 'y'
```

Make data.frame:

```
dt <- data.frame(x, y)
```

And now, I got error

```
model <- neuralnet(y~., dt, hidden=10, threshold=0.01)
```

> error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data'
>   argument

For example, in lm(linear model) this is worked.

Comment: `neuralnet` is doing a lot os messing with the formula via non-exported function `neuralnet:::generate.initial.variables`. There is a bug in that function. I suggest you contact the maintainer and send them this example or a link to the question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As my comment states, this looks like a bug in the non-exported function `neuralnet:::generate.initial.variables`. As a work around, just build a long formula from the names of `dt`, excluding `y`, e.g.

```
n <- names(dt)
f <- as.formula(paste("y ~", paste(n[!n %in% "y"], collapse = " + ")))
f

## gives
> f
y ~ x1 + x2

## fit model using `f`
model <- neuralnet(f, data = dt, hidden=10, threshold=0.01)

> model
Call: neuralnet(formula = f, data = dt, hidden = 10, threshold = 0.01)

1 repetition was calculated.

        Error Reached Threshold Steps
1 53975276.25     0.00857558698  1967
```

Comment: sorry, but I can't understand. Why error value is so big? So I did, but got constant predicted value. Can you help me?

Comment: @luckyi That is likely a statistics question and is not suited to [so] Try asking on [stats.se].

Comment: This also happens in package RMS for ols().  The same fix works there too

Comment: @GavinSimpson - Thanks for the solution, Gavin! I've encountered the same formula error in the new mpath package.

Comment: it doesn't remove the y values from the left hand side of formula. It comes in the end.

Answer (score 15):

Offering a simpler alternative to the previous answer, you can create a formula from names of `dt` using `reformulate()`:

```
f <- reformulate(setdiff(colnames(dt), "y"), response="y")
```

`reformulate()` doesn't require the use of `paste()` and automatically adds the terms together.

Comment: I've been searching for this,,,,,

Answer (score -1):

To expand a formula

```
f <- formula(terms(f, data= dt))
```

or even shorter

```
f <- formula(dt, f)
```

where `f` is the formula and `dt` is the data.

---

For instance, the original formula could be:

```
f <- as.formula("y ~ .")
```

Comment: Really confusing answer